# Matlab tex file specify column delimiters

Tags: matlab, replace, latex, delimiter, text-processing

I am creating a tex file in Matlab. The end goal is to create a pdf using latex. I have using following website to check the latex I have is correct [latex generator](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/). Everything is fine about from when I have a number that contains comma's for example 5,236,012. The issue comes when I copy the data from the tex file. The column delimiter is set to Commas, how can I change this to Semicolon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strrep` -

```
%%// input_filepath and output_filepath are the filepaths of the 
%%// input and output tex files

data = importdata(input_filepath);
datacell = strrep(data,',',';');

%%// Save as a text file
fid2 = fopen(output_filepath,'w');
for k = 1:size(datacell,1)
    fprintf(fid2,'%s\n',datacell{k,:});
end
fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: when I try the code above and open my tex file in Matlab the option box Column delimiters has no options selected. The output shows the number, 5,;326,;145. Is there anyway to change the default column delimiter in a tex file so that it ignores the commas?

Comment: Try the edited code. You need to open the tex file using the command `importdata` as listed in the code and not by the File Menu of MATLAB.