# MATLAB: how to sort a matrix by a specific column name and also let the row names follow the order?

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing, cell-array

I am new to MATLAB. I have a data structure named `da`. I want to sort the first column of `da.mat` and want to let `da.rid` and the other columns to follow the rearranged order. `da.cid` contains the column names and `da.rid` contains the row IDs.

```
da = 
    mat: [22268x377 single]
    rid: {22268x1 cell}
    rhd: {''}
  rdesc: {22268x1 cell}
    cid: {377x1 cell}
    chd: {0x1 cell}
  cdesc: {377x0 cell}
```

Also, if I want to use some other column instead of the first column of `da.mat` and which I will get from `da.cid`, how can I acheive it?
For example, if I want to look for the column name `'A02'` in `cid` and use it to select the specific column of `da.mat` for sorting. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Woody

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My question is actually very different. I want to sort one of the columns in the data structure and make the other columns (especially the rid) follow the same order.

Comment: I withdraw my duplicate

Comment: By `other columns` what do you mean? That is `other` columns of other fields? If so, how is that possible, because other fields aren't of the same size as `da.mat`.

Comment: Yes, I meant the other columns in the da.mat itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by other columns, you mean other columns of `da.mat` itself, you may try this -

```
[val,ind] = sort(da.mat(:,1))
da.mat = da.mat(ind,:)
da.rid = da.rid(ind)
```

If you are looking to use some other column number instead of `1` for sorting and based on the names in the field `cid`, use this -

```
cid_matchcol =  'A02'; %// column name to be used from `da.cid` to choose column of `da.mat`

base_col = find(strcmp(da.cid,cid_matchcol),1)
[val,ind] = sort(da.mat(:,base_col))
da.mat = da.mat(ind,:)
da.rid = da.rid(ind)
```

Comment: By sorting the first column with da.mat(:,1), you extracted its value and index. Then, you assign the index to rid. Yes, this is what I wanted! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Divakar, Could you explain more closely what da.mat(ind,:) does? Aren't ind only the index? How does the matlab know which column to sort?

Comment: `da.mat(ind,:)` has `:` that tells MATLAB to sort all columns. If I had written `da.mat(ind,2)`, it will sort only the second column, `da.mat(ind,3)` for the 3rd column and so on.

Comment: Also, Can I specify the column names with cid for sort(da.mat(:,1))?

Comment: column names or column numbers?

Comment: cid contains the column names.

Comment: Well you can't index into columns of matrices with just names and by names I am assuming strings. You need numbers starting from 1. Like if column name is `'col1'`, you can't say `da.mat(ind,'col1')`, as it doesn't make sense to MATLAB.

Comment: But I should be able to derive the column index from column names, right? For example, `col1` has a index number `1` in `cid`.

Comment: Give us some sample `cid` values? Those might give us some idea on what you are looking for though. `'col1'` was just an example. What if in `cid` you have names like {'john', 'mike'}, how would MATLAB know then?

Comment: `cid` has column names such as `A01`, `A02`, `A03` and so forth. I hope to sort the `A02` column. `A02` should be the second column. It should be written as `sort(da.mat(:,2))`. I just want to replace the `2` with `A02`.

Comment: I am thinking if we could derived the index number from `cid` based on the column name `A02`. And, we could put the index number to replace `2`.

Comment: Thanks! It is what I was expecting! The `find()` function!

Comment: Maybe add this extra requirement of using `da.cid` to index into the columns of `da.mat` into your question and thus make it very safe from   attributing it as a duplicate question? This way the additional code would stay in context too, as comments gets deleted by mods often.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look if I need to add more things. Thanks for helps sincerely.

Comment: Made few edits to your question. Hope they didn't diverge from your original intentions.

Comment: Follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23511916/3293881) and use the final 5 lines of the code